# GAE federated login and Linkedin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, linkedin-api, twitter-oauth

Hi I follow the given example for federated authentication in GAE.
 [Using Federated Authentication via OpenID in Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid)

In given example its provide the authentication of **yahoo**, **google**, **myspace** etc. I want to modify this example and provide the authentication of **linkedin** and **twitter**. Please tell me a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE federated login uses OpenID protocol, which is supported by Yahoo, Google and Myspace. LinkedIn and Twitter do not support OpenID, instead they support OAuth.

Note: the [GAE Oauth docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/) explain how your GAE app can be an OAuth provider (= other apps gain access to your app on behalf of users). What you are looking for is your app acting as OAuth consumer: your app accesses 3rd party profiles (LinkedIn, Twitter) on behalf of the users.

See [pac4j-oauth](https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j) OAuth client lib that enables you to authenticate users against various providers, including Google, Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter. It also enables accessing user's profile.